# hidd process generates error messages in Console

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

The following error messages are continuously being generated when I move the mouse or type on the keyboard. I recently updated for Catalina but I am not sure if this has persisted from before.

```
error   10:33:01.055334-0800    hidd    No assertion name string for service:10000055f
error   10:33:01.314146-0800    hidd    Error generating assertion string
error   10:33:01.314169-0800    hidd    No assertion name string for service:10000055f
error   10:33:01.573014-0800    hidd    Error generating assertion string
error   10:33:01.573043-0800    hidd    No assertion name string for service:10000055f
error   10:33:02.247905-0800    hidd    Error generating assertion string
```

I can't find any references to these errors on the web. Anyone have any idea why they are being generated?

Edit: I figured out that this is happening only when using Bluetooth Apple mouse and keyboard, but does not occur with another USB mouse.